# Simple application execution logging and control over Internet in JAVA?

Tags: java, web-services

I would like to implement a simple system to control the execution of my applications.

Ideally I would like the following functionality:

1. System checks if remote server S predefined during program compilation time is responding.
2. If it is not responding, nothing happens and execution continues. Otherwise:

   1. System accesses a file on a server S.
   2. Depending on file content (e.g. licence) program either continues or stops.
   3. An access to the file is also registered with the IP, date, etc. and stored on the server.

I am aware that I can implement this functionality with pure Java client / server code or some other API called from java client (e.g. JSON calls), but I am searching for already existing  library or chunk of code doing a "version" of above. I suspect it should be present in one of many licence management systems or web-loggers, but I would like to hear some names.

Thank you for any advice or tip.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're going for, but you could use a Servlet.

Comment: parse the input stream from a URL and store the result in a database like derby?  Probably less than two pages of code.

Answer (score 1):

You could roll your own, or just use https://truelicense.java.net/features.html or http://java.nicholaswilliams.net/LicenseManager/ as they pretty much do what you want already. You can add the specific logging that you want to either of these solutions.